# Ruby - Parsing XML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm not familiar with XML and trying to get a bit network automation going. I get some XML responses like the following, and try to convert it to a hash or something to easily work with it. I have no idea if I'm doing something wrong. I get the output shown below.

Anyone can push me into a direction ? I tried the nokogiri documentation and guides, but I'm kinda lost.

My Data:

```
"show ip int brief vrf all | xml\r\n" +
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\n" +
"<nf:rpc-reply xmlns:nf=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:ip\">\n" +
" <nf:data>\n" +
"  <show>\n" +
"   <ip>\n" +
"    <interface>\n" +
"     <__XML__BLK_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_brief>\n" +
"      <__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_operational>\n" +
"       <__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_vrf>\n" +
"        <__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command___readonly__>\n" +
"         <__readonly__>\n" +
"          <TABLE_vrf>\n" +
"           <ROW_vrf>\n" +
"            <vrf-name-out>management</vrf-name-out>\n" +
"           </ROW_vrf>\n" +
"          </TABLE_vrf>\n" +
"          <TABLE_intf>\n" +
"           <ROW_intf>\n" +
"            <intf-name>mgmt0</intf-name>\n" +
"            <prefix>10.70.237.15</prefix>\n" +
"            <ip-disabled>FALSE</ip-disabled>\n" +
"            <iod>316</iod>\n" +
"            <proto-state>up</proto-state>\n" +
"            <link-state>up</link-state>\n" +
"            <admin-state>up</admin-state>\n" +
"           </ROW_intf>\n" +
"          </TABLE_intf>\n" +
"         </__readonly__>\n" +
"        </__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command___readonly__>\n" +
"       </__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_vrf>\n" +
"      </__XML__OPT_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_operational>\n" +
"     </__XML__BLK_Cmd_ip_show_interface_command_brief>\n" +
"    </interface>\n" +
"   </ip>\n" +
"  </show>\n" +
" </nf:data>\n" +
"</nf:rpc-reply>\n" +


2.4.1 :363 > doc = Nokogiri::XML(my_data)
 => #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x173dda8 name="document"> 
2.4.1 :364 > doc.elements
 => []
```

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of anything before `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>` XML declaration - in you case, omit `"show ip int brief vrf all | xml\r\n"` line.

Once your document is parsed, follow [official tutorial on searching](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) - for a beginner IMHO it's best to avoid Xpath and just stick with `.css` selectors, which will be easy to grasp if you've ever done any CSS or Jquery.

Comment: oh gosh, that was exactly my issue. Now i get something to work with. I will check the tutorial, thanks a lot !